# puppet variable as a variable

Tags: puppet

Can a variable name be derived from a variable?

```
$hash01={instance => '01',street => 'blah'}
```

This works to call a define:

```
mydefine { '01': hash => $mod::params::hash01 }
```

Can this work? (I'm interested in the hash var concat)

```
$var='01'

mydefine { $var: hash => $mod::params::hash"$var" }
```

Answer (score 3):

I've used inline_template() and scope.lookupvar() for this:

```
$mod::params::hash01={instance => '01',street => 'blah'}
$var='01'
$hash_name="mod::params::hash$var"
$hash=inline_template("<%= scope.lookupvar(hash_name) %>")
```

However inline_template always returns strings, so it would return the string "streetblahinstance01", which is not going to work since your function is expecting a hash.

Another approach would be to avoid the problem by using an array of hashes.  Note the array indices start at 0.

```
$mod::param::hashes=[{instance=>'00',street=>'fooblah'},{instance=>'01',street=>'blah'}]
mydefine { $var : hash => $mod::param::hashes[1] }
```

See https://blog.kumina.nl/tag/inline_template/

Comment: I discovered getvar in stdlib and this proved to be the most appropriate solution for the original question.  Thank you, as your 2nd approach is very interesting.